# Matlab stairs plot doesn't start from the origin

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a binary input using stairs, but the data doesn't start from zero. So how to make the plot starts from zero instead of one?

Matlab Code:

```
a = [ 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ];
stairs(a); 
axis([0 14 -0.5 1.5 ]);
grid on;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the x vector, in order to clarify where your data start on the x axis.

```
y = round(rand(1,10)); %binary vector
x = [0:length(y)-1]; %[0,1,2,3,4....]
stairs(x,y);
axis([0,10,-0.5,1.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the help for the [plot command](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html):

> plot(Y) creates a 2-D line plot of the data in Y versus the index of
>   each value.
>
> ```
>     If Y is a vector, then the x-axis scale ranges from 1 to length(Y).
>
>     If Y is a matrix, then the plot function plots the columns of Y versus their row number. The x-axis scale ranges from 1 to the
> ```
>
> number of rows in Y.
>
> ```
> If Y is complex, then the plot function plots the imaginary part of Y versus the real part of Y, such that plot(Y) is equivalent to
> ```
>
> plot(real(Y),imag(Y)).

To plot starting from zero:
vectors: plot(0:length(y) - 1, y)
matrices: plot(0:size(M, 1) - 1, M)

The same applies to stairs, the easy way of starting at 0 is to add the x axis to your plot, easily like this:

```
>> stairs(0:length(a)-1,a),axis([0 14 -0.5 1.5 ]);grid on;
```